# Search through .select().group().distinct possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a search select that works on unique names through grouping...

The **goal** is to find duplicates to then use as a search parameter.

I want to find `LineItem`'s `:store_title`'s that match so I can create a select drop down for a way to search through `LineItem`'s that match the specific `:store_title`.

**Example:**
LineItem DB:

`line_item.title = "Hello"`

`line_item.title = "Hello"`

`line_item.title = "Okay"`

`line_item.title = "Bar"`

I want to have a drop down select_tag in a search for the following:

- [select]
- "Hello"
- "Okay"
- "Bar"

And append all results that match `LineItem.title` of those which is selected.

I tried a few ways:

I so far have been able to get the unique drop down select field to "work" but not sure if it is the right way because it creates an array:

**Controller:**

```
@vendor_line_items = LineItem.where(vendor_id: @vendor.id).select(:store_title).group(:store_title).distinct

if params[:search]
   @orders = Order.line_item_search(params[:search]).joins(:line_items).where(line_items: {vendor_id: @vendor.id})
end
```

**ORders Model:**

```
def self.line_item_search(search)
    scope = joins(:line_items)
    line_items = scope.where(line_items: { id: LineItem.where(store_title: "#{search.downcase}") })
    line_items
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= form_tag vendor_orders_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= collection_select(:search, params[:search], @vendor_line_items, :store_title, :store_title, {}, {class: "form-control-sm col-5"})%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
<% end %>
```

**Error:**

> Undefined method 'downcase' for ["store_title"]:Array:

Can I alter my model to allow the array, or should i be finding the unique store titles another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried finding a way to remove the brackets before searching so the brackets were not present in the search parameters but couldn't figure it out.

Doing...:

```
line_items = scope.where(line_items: { id: LineItem.where(store_title: "#{search.join(', ')}") })
```

Solved it.  This removes the brackets before searching the DB and works.

**

### UPDATE:

**

View for response and answer to my issue:

[Rails search form through arrays doesn't work on second search attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044045/rails-search-form-through-arrays-doesnt-work-on-second-search-attempt/58045187#58045187)

Comment: BTW, this is not an accepted answer as is because it doesn't work on second search parameter.  Still testing new code

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to downcase the strings in that array, you could do something like this:

```
line_items = scope.where(line_items: { id: LineItem.where(store_title: search.map(&:downcase)) })
```

That will provide a list of downcased strings to your query.