# Rails search form through arrays doesn't work on second search attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did the following to be able to search through unique attributes (removing duplicates) with a select dropdown.

The issue is that when submitting a search after an initial search, it breaks.

**View:**

```
<%= form_tag vendor_orders_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= collection_select(:search, params[:search], @vendor_line_items, :store_title, :store_title, {}, {class: "form-control-sm col-5"})%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
```

**Model:**

```
def self.line_item_search(search)
    scope = joins(:line_items)
    line_items = scope.where(line_items: { id: LineItem.where(store_title: "#{search.join(', ')}") })
    line_items
  end
```

**Note**: `.join(', ')`  This allows me to search through the Array parameter.

**Controller:**

```
if params[:search]
    @orders = Order.line_item_search(params[:search]).joins(:line_items).where(line_items: {vendor_id: @vendor.id})
end
```

**Errors:**

This all works on the first search.  But when I search twice (after a successful search), it breaks with the following params and errors:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"\"Copy of Copy of t-shirt 123\""=>"Copy of Copy of t-shirt 123"}}

NoMethodError (undefined method `join' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f45a47f9428>):
```

It is stating the error is in line 73 in the controller which is:

```
@orders = Order.line_item_search(params[:search]).joins(:line_items).where(line_items: {vendor_id: @vendor.id})
```

**Questions** and possible alternatives:

How can I clear the previous search in the url?

Is there a better way to go about getting the unique attributes from the LineItem model?  In the past, when using search forms, I never had this issue when it was just using a string or an integer.  I assume clearing the search results isn't the best solution as much as just getting a list of strings to not need to use `.join(', ')` to get the search results.

What are your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
  <%= select_tag :search, options_from_collection_for_select(@vendor_line_items, :store_title, :store_title, params[:search]), class: "form-control-sm col-5" %>
```

Instead of `collection_select` solved all issues.  It turned the select into a string, without the need of using .join(', ') in the model.  And it allowed searching after a search

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is with your form. Why are you feeding in a second argument of params[:search] into `collection_select`?

See https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select for which arguments you need and where

Comment: I don't think you can have a search form without it.  I attempted it without, nothing would work but i figured out my issue because of your post.  I ended up just beeding to use `select_tag` and `options_from_collection_for_select`